# Unable to find newly saved instances in database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making a stock portfolio app as a personal project. I have a form `StockSymbolForm` used for buying stocks. It has the fields: `username`, `stock_symbol`, and `stock_qty`.

I've set `username` to be the current user that's currently using the app - so they only need to fill `stock_symbol` and `stock_qty`.

After a valid form is submitted, I go to my admin page to check, but I don't see my new `stock_symbol` and `stock_qty` added to my model.

Here's my code:

**views.py**:

class PortfolioStockListView(ListView):
    model = StockPortfolio
    template_name = 'stocks.html'

```
def post(self, request):
    current_user = StockPortfolioUser.objects.filter(username=request.user).first()

if request.method == 'POST':
    symbol_form = StockSymbolForm(request.POST, initial={'username': current_user})

    if symbol_form.is_valid():
        symbol_form = StockSymbolForm(request.POST, instance=current_user)
        model_instance = symbol_form.save(commit=True)
        model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
        model_instance.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:   
        return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'symbol_form': symbol_form})

else:
    symbol_form = StockSymbolForm()

return render(request, 'stocks.html', {'symbol_form': symbol_form})
```

**models.py**:

```
class StockPortfolioUser(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usercash = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100000)

class StockPortfolio(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(StockPortfolioUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    stock_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**forms.py**:

class StockSymbolForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = StockPortfolio
    fields = ('stock_symbol' , 'stock_qty')
    labels = {'stock_symbol': 'Stock Symbol', 'stock_qty': 'Quantity'}
```

---

How do I save the model instance properly? and why is it not saving at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `views.py` file change this

```
model_instance = symbol_form.save(commit=False)
model_instance.username = request.user.id
model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
model_instance.save()
```

In `StockSymbolForm` change this

```
fields = ('username', 'stock_symbol' , 'stock_qty')
```

Comment: I just realized my main mistake, I needed to not commit first and get the username, then save. I did something similar to this, but rather than `request.user.id` I used `current_user = StockPortfolioUser.objects.get(username=request.user)` yours is neater though!

Comment: Yep, your username field accept a foreign key value not a string. SO you need to assign an id to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't ever seem to be setting the username. You set a timestamp, which doesn't exist as a field, but not the actual username field.

```
    model_instance = symbol_form.save(commit=True)
    model_instance.userame = request.user
    model_instance.save()
```

As an aside, that field should be called `user`, as it points to the whole User object not just the username.

Comment: Thank you I will keep that in mind and change it to `user` after the problem is fixed. I've removed the timestamp in the meantime. I've did the above, I can see the username obtained properly and the form fields filled out, but when I go to admin, the changes aren't there. Is there like something I need to do to "update" the db aside from saving?